# How to pass a tuple to a python function using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I have two methods max(x, y) and min(x, y) which return maximum and minimum values of the arguments passed to them respectively.

I need to make a call to each one of them using lambda function something like...

```
funWithNum = [lambda  x: funWithNum[0], max  ,  lambda y: funWithNum[1], min]
print funWithNum[0](1, 2)
print funWithNum[1](1, 2)
```

When I use `print funWithNum[0](1, 2)`, I should get max number and when I use `print funWithNum[1](1, 2)`, I should get min number. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hint: How would you do it if you didn't have `lambda`?

Comment: Why not just put `max` and `min` in the list, nothing else?

Comment: classic XY problem. Describe what you want to do, not how

Comment: The first `lambda` function returns itself. The second one returns `max`. I recommend doing some more research on what `lambda` is.

Comment: You say that `max` & `min` are methods, but in your code they look more like ordinary functions. Are they functions that you've written, or are they Python's built-in `max` & `min` functions?

Answer (score 7):

Why does everyone always think they need lambda functions!? You don't.

```
>>> fwn = [max, min]
>>> fwn[0](1,2)
2
>>> fwn[1](1, 2)
1
```